# After installing nfs-common I get "Failed to resolve server nfs-server"

Tags: linux, nfs

Hi am following this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) I tried to run this:

sudo

```
 mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 nfs-server:/ /dev
```

after installing this:

```
apt-get install nfs-common
```

and get this error

```
Failed to resolve server nfs-server: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change "nfs-server" to an ip-address, eg.

```
mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2409 192.168.1.1:/ /dev
```

Comment: some easy points for ya!